# Function to check users credentials not able to find username

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a web server that I am trying to learn how to create a login and registration page with mongoDB and node.js. My post request for logging in calls the function checkUser which is supposed to check the username and password for the user logging in. When I attempt to login with a username and password I know is in my database I get the error Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

My checkUser function:

```
function checkUser(userData) {
    return User.find({ userName: userData.userName }).exec().then((user) => {
        if (user == undefined || user.length == 0) {
            throw new Error("Unable to find user: " + userData.userName);
        }
        else if (user[0].password != userData.password) {
            throw new Error("Incorrect Password for user: " + userData.userName);
        }
        else if (user[0].password == userData.password) 
        {
            user[0].loginHistory.push({
                dateTime: (new Date()).toString(), 
                userAgent: userData.userAgent});
            user[0].update({
                userName: userData.userName}, {$set: {loginHistory: user[0].loginHistory}}).exec().then((user) => {
                return user[0];
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(err.stack);
               throw new Error("There was an error verifying the user: ${err}");
            })
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.stack);
        throw new Error("Unable to find user: " + err);
    });
};
```

My Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    "userName": {
        unique: true,
        type: String
    },
    "password": String,
    "email": String,
    "loginHistory": [{ "dateTime": Date, "userAgent": String }]
});

let User; //to be defined on new connection
```

I can see the user in the database I just cant seem to figure out how to make them able to log in.

Comment: are you getting any result set from .exec().then((user) => {}? can you console.log(user)?

Comment: Yes I get the username and password that i am typing in back.

Comment: are you saying that you are getting correct result set from db after executing User.find() query?

Comment: [ { loginHistory: [],
    _id: 5ad03fba32b26a2bd06739e4,
    userName: 'a',
    password: 'a',
    email: 'a@a.a',
    __v: 0 } ] 
is my response when doing console.log(user) right after the find()